# Videos of surgery

Tags: surgery, practice-of-medicine, trauma, video

Where can I find a website which contains videos of open trauma (HD if possible)? I want to accustom to these views (because I am a medical student).

Comment: Depending on where you live, there are paramedic programs that happily accept med students, as another set of helping hands with good knowledge is always welcome. And you'd get lots of practice and desensitization.

Comment: @jaaq I'd be shocked to see a med student in a paramedic program in the US. Depending on location, paramedic training can be up to two years of classwork followed by weeks of on-the-job training, which will mean long shifts. I doubt any med student would have the time.

Comment: @CareyGregory yes, the american paramedic system is very much different from where I come from, with highly different priorities. Over here we only focus on stabilizing and transport, since the average distance to the next hospital here is <15 minutes; if it'd take longer we get a helicopter instead. Basic paramedic training here can be completed within 3 months working/training 50 hrs a week as part of the military draft exemption programme. After that we're fully certified for the job; but as I said, much different (smaller)skillset than in the US, but well equiped for all tasks at hand.

Comment: @jaaq What you describe would be an EMT-B in the US.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Top quality resources for videos will be found at sites from surgical academies, which often offer free or low-price subscriptions to students/residents/trainees:

- **American College of Surgeons** curriculum for residents at https://cine-med.com/acsonline/
- **American College of Surgeons Journal** at https://www.journalacs.org/featuredvideo
- **Journal of Trauma and Acute Care Surgery** at  https://journals.lww.com/jtrauma/Pages/videogallery.aspx
- **Society of American Gastrointestinal and Endoscopic Surgeons** at https://www.sages.org/video/
- **American College of Obstetricians and Gynecologists** at https://cfweb.acog.org/onlinevideos/

Other sites I have not thoroughly explored but appear to offer quite a bit:

- https://medschool.ucsd.edu/som/surgery/divisions/trauma-burn/training/videos/Pages/Videos.aspx
- https://www.csurgeries.com/

Uncertain of quality:

- https://medtube.net/

**Regarding desensitization** to blood, surgery, trauma, deliveries, and the like, watching videos definitely will help.  However, there is nothing that can replace the real thing - especially when you are actively involved in the cutting, cleaning, suctioning, retracting, stretching, etc.  Be very aware of this, and consider spending time shadowing in the ER or OR as an observer (i.e. able to leave at any time) before you need to take an active role in the procedure.

Therefore additionally, I want to encourage you that if you are expected to be part of a surgical team and know there is a possibility that you may experience nausea/vomiting, lightheadedness, or syncope: **it is your professional and ethical responsibility to inform t**he chief resident and/or attending, as well as the circulating and/or scrub nurse, **so that they can plan for your replacement if anything happens.**

Secondly, the **second that you notice symptoms or feel you are becoming overwhelmed, it is imperative that you tell the person who will replace you,** hand over your task, and remove yourself from the surgical field.  Sit right there on the floor if you have to, but try to avoid (1) faceplanting into the open surgical field of the patient's body or (2) fainting in the trauma bay or OR and hitting your head on the tile floor, becoming a trauma patient yourself.  I had classmates with such stories and it was horrifically embarrassing for them.

Instead, be more like a certain medical student who told their attending and the circulating nurse that they'd done extensive desensitization training but this was their first real surgical case.  So then after a prolonged surgery with heavy blood loss, when they overheated after sweating for hours in the scrub suit and began to vaso-vagal, someone was already scrubbed in to take over for them immediately - and they could remove themselves to a safe spot to sit.  Rather than be humiliated by contaminating the field or becoming a patient themself, they were thanked for being responsible and self aware.

Comment: A good German resource is [Sectio Chirurgica](https://www.sectio-chirurgica.de/).

Comment: I saw the links but .. for me I prefer trauma which appear from outsite (without endoscopy or internal surgery), like trauma orthopaedic ... you can say all trauma with discontinuity off skin. Because my problem is like what you said : symptoms vaso-vagal !

Comment: If you have some experience (from your friends) about a solution for the problem, try help me, because it is impossible for me to enter an operation room then to quit it (because it is sterile).

Comment: @user16752 You can always exit the operating room. Because it is sterile you will need to go through all checks to come back in. Also, operating rooms have multiples stages of hygiene, usually as medical students you are not sterile and can not enter the surgical field, but considered sterile enough (due to different clothing etc.) so that you can pass through the scrub room into the operating theatre. Nothing prevents you from leaving the theatre, sitting down in the scrub room and taking a break. I did it myself a few times.

Comment: Even if you are scrubbed in (sterile) there is NOTHING stopping you from walking out of the OR.  The issue is that if you are participating, they NEED TO KNOW whether you might have to leave so they have backup.

Comment: I struggled with this too.  What helped me was focusing on the importance of protecting the patient's life, the anatomy involved, and being as technical about it as possible.  It usually goes away with time.  Repeat exposure helps a lot.  Now I can do anything without reacting to it.

Comment: In the US it is common for med students to scrub in to the surgery and participate in retracting, cauterizing, suctioning, and other assisting duties.  Often they get a chance to do sterile prep and suture as well, and more for those who show ability and an interest in surgical specialties

Comment: @DoctorWhom Ah okay yeah it depends here whether you do an internship or just pop by electively. Sometimes in the earlier years of studying they just watch; I kinda let the part slip when you get to participate. But even then as you said, nothing stops anybody from simply walking out of the OR

Comment: Ok, I will try all what you have say ;) I will focus in the life of patient and trry to forget my feelings.